# Update quiz tracker answer DIVs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a simple quiz app with vanilla JavaScript and HTML. The functionality to know if the chosen answer is correct or incorrect and display some feedback is working, but not the functionality to set the `.quiz__marker` div's data-attribute to "Correct" or "Incorrect" when the question's radio button is selected. My simplified code is included in the snippet below.

I have set the `.quiz__marker` divs to either be green or red depending on if the correct or incorrect answer is selected. As you can see, all of the circles are set to green or red when the radio button is selected.

How should I adjust my JS code to only apply the color change to a single circle? Also, what would I need to implement to have the color maintained throughout the quiz duration?

I am learning JavaScript as I go. Vanilla JS answers are preferred.

Cheers!

**Update - Included full quiz.js for review purposes**

```
function answerTracker() {
  const tracker = document.querySelector(".quiz__tracker");
  // Each quiz contains eight or less questions
  const questions = 8;
  for (let i = 1; i <= questions; i++) {
    let trackerMarker = document.createElement("div");
    trackerMarker.className = "quiz__marker";
    trackerMarker.id = "marker_" + i;
    trackerMarker.setAttribute("data-answer", "");
    tracker.appendChild(trackerMarker);
  }
}

function questionMarkers() {
  let labels = document.querySelectorAll("div[class*='rsform-block-question'] .formControlLabel");
  let count = labels.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let marker = `<span class="question-marker">${i + 1}</span>`;
    labels[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", marker);
  }
}

const runQuiz = (() => {
  // Generate tracker
  answerTracker();

  // Append question markers to labels
  questionMarkers();

  // Set quiz score to zero
  let score = 0;

  let markers = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz__marker");

  let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".rsform-radio");
  answers.forEach(function (answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let target    = e.target;
      let container = target.closest(".formContainer");
      let correct   = container.querySelector("div[class$='true']");
      let wrong     = container.querySelector("div[class$='false']");
      let feedback  = container.querySelector("div[class$='feedback']");
      let question  = container.querySelector("div[class*='rsform-block-question']");
      let next      = container.querySelector(".js-btn--next.success");
      let submit    = container.querySelector(".js-btn--submit.rsform-submit-button");

      if (e.target.value == "t") {
        // If answer is correct, increment the user's score by one
        score++;
        correct.style.display = "block";
        wrong.style.display = "none";
        feedback.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("marker_" + e.target.dataset.num).setAttribute("data-answer", "Correct");
      } else {
        correct.style.display = "none";
        wrong.style.display = "block";
        feedback.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("marker_" + e.target.dataset.num).setAttribute("data-answer", "Incorrect");
      }
  
      if (next !== null && next !== "") {
        next.style.display = "block";
      }
  
      if (submit !== null && submit !== "") {
        submit.style.display = "block";
      }
      question.style.display = "none";
    });
  });
  // If this is the final question in the quiz, assign the score variable to the final-score hidden HTML field
  // document.getElementById("final-score").value = score;
})();
```

```js
function answerTracker() {
  const tracker = document.querySelector(".quiz__sidebar");
  // Each quiz contains eight questions
  const questions = 8;
  for (let i = 1; i <= questions; i++) {
    let trackerMarker = document.createElement("div");
    trackerMarker.className = "quiz__marker";
    trackerMarker.setAttribute("data-answer", "");
    tracker.appendChild(trackerMarker);
  }
}

const runQuiz = (() => {
  // Generate answer tracker
  answerTracker();

  // Set quiz score to zero
  let score = 0;

  // Get node list of .quiz__marker DIVs
  let markers = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz__marker");

  // Get node list of answer radio buttons
  let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".rsform-radio");

  answers.forEach(function(answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let target = e.target;
      let container = target.closest(".formContainer");
      let correct = container.querySelector("div[class$='true']");
      let wrong = container.querySelector("div[class$='false']");
      let feedback = container.querySelector("div[class$='feedback']");
      let question = container.querySelector("div[class*='rsform-block-question']");
      let next = container.querySelector(".js-btn--next.success");

      if (e.target.value == "t") {
        // If answer is correct, increment the user's score by one
        score++;
        correct.style.display = "block";
        wrong.style.display = "none";
        feedback.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        correct.style.display = "none";
        wrong.style.display = "block";
        feedback.style.display = "block";
      }

      // Loop through node list and set data-attribute to "Correct" or "Incorrect" depending on e.target value
      Array.from(markers).forEach(link => {
        if (e.target.value == "t") {
          link.setAttribute("data-answer", "Correct");
        } else {
          link.setAttribute("data-answer", "Incorrect");
        }
      });

      // If question has been answered, display the next button
      if (next !== null && next !== "") {
        next.style.display = "block";
      }

    });
  });

  // If this is the final question in the quiz, assign the score variable to the final-score hidden HTML field
  // document.getElementById("final-score").value = score;
})();
```

```css
.quiz__sidebar .quiz__marker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 6px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.quiz__sidebar .quiz__marker[data-answer="Correct"] {
  background-color: green;
}

.quiz__sidebar .quiz__marker[data-answer="Incorrect"] {
  background-color: red;
}

form.quiz__form .formHidden,
form.quiz__form div[class$="true"],
form.quiz__form div[class$="false"],
form.quiz__form div[class$="feedback"],
form.quiz__form .rsform-block .rsform-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <div class="quiz__sidebar"></div>
  <form class="quiz__form">
    <div class="formContainer">
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one0">To attract a mate</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="t" id="question-one1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one1">To defend themselves against predators</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one2">To mark their territory</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one3" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one3">Because they like the smell</label>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one-true">
        <p>
          <strong>Correct!</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one-false">
        <p>
          <strong>Nice try</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one-feedback">
        <p>Skunks spray an extremely offensive odour to make predators go away and leave them alone. If they feel their life is in danger, they have no other defence as they cannot run fast, climb, burrow under the ground, or fight.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn--next js-btn--next rsform-button success button" style="display: none;">
                    Next
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formContainer formHidden">
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two0">1 cup</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two1">Endless supply</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="t" id="question-two2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two2">2 tbsp</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two3" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two3">1 tsp</label>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two-true">
        <p>
          <strong>Correct!</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two-false">
        <p>
          <strong>Nice try</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two-feedback">
        <p>Skunks have only 2 tbsp (30ml) of spray and it takes them more than a week to re-supply. They cannot spray every day as they will simply run out. Skunks use spraying as a last resort only as if they run out, they are defenceless against predators.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn--next js-btn--next rsform-button success button" style="display: none;">
                    Next
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd certainly make CSS classes for instance .wrong/.right; and apply those attributes each answer, so say they answer B (reference to the element will be made and you will set it wrong/right.

Comment: Please check the answer i posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some characteristic "markers" for the quiz markers, for example an id with the question number:

```
  for (let i = 1; i <= questions; i++) {
    let trackerMarker = document.createElement("div");
    trackerMarker.className = "quiz__marker";
    trackerMarker.id = "marker_" + i; // specific id for each marker
    trackerMarker.setAttribute("data-answer", "");
    tracker.appendChild(trackerMarker);
  }
```

and then don't loop through every marker - set the color for the marker with the same number as the question. Something like:

```
document.getElementById("marker_" + questionNumber).setAttribute("data-answer", "Correct");
```

I can't see the code to handle click on the next button, but it doesn't matter for the question.

```js
function answerTracker() {
  const tracker = document.querySelector(".quiz__sidebar");
  // Each quiz contains eight questions
  const questions = 8;
  for (let i = 1; i <= questions; i++) {
    let trackerMarker = document.createElement("div");
    trackerMarker.className = "quiz__marker";
    trackerMarker.id = "marker_" + i;
    trackerMarker.setAttribute("data-answer", "");
    tracker.appendChild(trackerMarker);
  }
}

const runQuiz = (() => {
  // Generate answer tracker
  answerTracker();

  // Set quiz score to zero
  let score = 0;

  // Get node list of .quiz__marker DIVs
  let markers = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz__marker");

  // Get node list of answer radio buttons
  let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".rsform-radio");

  answers.forEach(function(answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let target = e.target;
      let container = target.closest(".formContainer");
      let correct = container.querySelector("div[class$='true']");
      let wrong = container.querySelector("div[class$='false']");
      let feedback = container.querySelector("div[class$='feedback']");
      let question = container.querySelector("div[class*='rsform-block-question']");
      let next = container.querySelector(".js-btn--next.success");

      if (e.target.value == "t") {
        // If answer is correct, increment the user's score by one
        score++;
        correct.style.display = "block";
        wrong.style.display = "none";
        feedback.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("marker_" + e.target.dataset.num).setAttribute("data-answer", "Correct");
      } else {
        correct.style.display = "none";
        wrong.style.display = "block";
        feedback.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("marker_" + e.target.dataset.num).setAttribute("data-answer", "Incorrect");
      }


      // If question has been answered, display the next button
      if (next !== null && next !== "") {
        next.style.display = "block";
      }

    });
  });

  // If this is the final question in the quiz, assign the score variable to the final-score hidden HTML field
  // document.getElementById("final-score").value = score;
})();
```

```css
.quiz__sidebar .quiz__marker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 6px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.quiz__sidebar .quiz__marker[data-answer="Correct"] {
  background-color: green;
}

.quiz__sidebar .quiz__marker[data-answer="Incorrect"] {
  background-color: red;
}

form.quiz__form .formHidden,
form.quiz__form div[class$="true"],
form.quiz__form div[class$="false"],
form.quiz__form div[class$="feedback"],
form.quiz__form .rsform-block .rsform-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <div class="quiz__sidebar"></div>
  <form class="quiz__form">
    <div class="formContainer">
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" data-num="1" value="f" id="question-one0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one0">To attract a mate</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" data-num="1" value="t" id="question-one1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one1">To defend themselves against predators</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" data-num="1" value="f" id="question-one2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one2">To mark their territory</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" data-num="1" value="f" id="question-one3" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one3">Because they like the smell</label>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one-true">
        <p>
          <strong>Correct!</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one-false">
        <p>
          <strong>Nice try</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-one-feedback">
        <p>Skunks spray an extremely offensive odour to make predators go away and leave them alone. If they feel their life is in danger, they have no other defence as they cannot run fast, climb, burrow under the ground, or fight.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn--next js-btn--next rsform-button success button" style="display: none;">
                    Next
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formContainer formHidden">
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" data-num="2" value="f" id="question-two0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two0">1 cup</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" data-num="2" value="f" id="question-two1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two1">Endless supply</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" data-num="2" value="t" id="question-two2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two2">2 tbsp</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" data-num="2" value="f" id="question-two3" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two3">1 tsp</label>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two-true">
        <p>
          <strong>Correct!</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two-false">
        <p>
          <strong>Nice try</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block-question-two-feedback">
        <p>Skunks have only 2 tbsp (30ml) of spray and it takes them more than a week to re-supply. They cannot spray every day as they will simply run out. Skunks use spraying as a last resort only as if they run out, they are defenceless against predators.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rsform-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn--next js-btn--next rsform-button success button" style="display: none;">
                    Next
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have implemented it on my staging site, but am getting this JS error in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null on line 58 of quiz.js. Here is the staging [link](http://staging.medicineriverwildlifecentre.ca/kids/quizzes/skunks). I have also updated my question with full JS from quiz.js for review.

Comment: Please ignore my first comment. I completely missed the `data-num` attribute you added to the radio buttons. I added it and the code is now working.